# delete rows based on checkbox selection in slickgrid

Tags: plugins, checkbox, slickgrid

i am taking help of this example: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html and add a checkbox column to my grid and assign unique_id value of my record to the id of checkbox column i am getting checked columns number using `grid.getSelectedRows();` 
it gives me a index number of row. how can i get id of this selected rows in slickgrid? please help me if anyone have any idea.

Comment: Maybe this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944325/get-data-of-selected-rows-in-slickgrid/7944426#7944426 will help You.

Comment: I have one problem when i am selecting row first time & then use grid.getSelectedRows(); it will give me correct answer but after deselecting previous one and selecting new row it will give me previous data + new data how can i solve this

Comment: @priyankapatel i m facing the simlir problem as u mention in last comment......how u solved it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectedrows = grid.getSelectedRows();            
for(i=0;i<len;i++){                        
var d = grid.getData().getItem(selectedrows[i]);                         
                        if(d != null && d != 'undefined'){
                              dataView.deleteItem(d.id);
                               grid.invalidate();                                   
                               grid.updateRowCount();
                               grid.render();
                        }
                    }
```

It removes rows from grid. not from server side.