# How to get unique row value selected in slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

I want to render only the selected line by using the invalidateRow(row) function in slickgrid. How can I get the row value of the selected row?

Comment: I'll mention again that you should think about providing what code you tried, you should also think about voting and/or accepting an answer if it was helpful. I suggest you to read this info: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [get data of selected rows in slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944325/get-data-of-selected-rows-in-slickgrid) and you can also just take a look at SlickGrid's code, it's easy enough to find all available methods directly from the code [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L6059).